# How to prevent automatic login of the last user in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

There was a pretty arcane [hack](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-automatic-logon-of-last-user-in-window-8/) that worked in Windows 8.1, but it doesn't work any more. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should describe the "hack" in your question. If the link ever goes dead then your question will be useless to both you and future visitors.

Comment: not sure about this, but try: Run secpol.msc as admin -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Interactive logon: Do not display last user name -> Enabled

Comment: @Divin3 thanks for a good suggestion, but it also disables the user list, and i have to type in the username manually. I'd rather be presented with the list of users, so i can log in with one click.

Comment: there are a few options for Windows 8 here: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/14632-sign-show-all-users-last-user-windows-8-a.html one of them should work for Win 10 as well.

Comment: These procedures don´t work. This does: http://superuser.com/questions/952868/can-i-disable-auto-logon-on-windows-10-home

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following works for me on Windows 10 Pro x64. It's particularly useful if some accounts don't have passwords.

- Go into the **Local Group Policy Editor** (you can get there by searching the configuration panel)
- In the navigation panel, click to expand the User Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Logon/Logoff)
- In the right panel, double click to open **Logon** (not Logoff!)
- In the windows that opens, click on Add
- In the **Script Name** field, input: `C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe`
- In the **Script Parameters** field, input: `ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserSwitch /V Enabled /T REG_dWORD /D 1 /F`
- Click OK and close the window
- Restart the PC (logging out might also suffice)

Now when you login and go to shut down the PC, you will be greeted by the list of user names at the next boot.

I have confirmed this works on my Windows accounts, but only if you put the script at the Logon, not the Logoff, which used to work for Windows 8.x. What this does is change a registry key to enable the User Switch (sets it to 1). Apparently, this registry key gets reset (set back to 0) by another process (likely during logon) and this Policy puts it back to 1.

Source: [Option Two of this Eight Forums tutorial](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/14632-sign-show-all-users-last-user-windows-8-a.html#option2)

Comment: This approach will make UAC crazy - see an example at http://www.briteccomputers.co.uk/forum/showthread.php?tid=222&pid=1238#pid1238

Comment: Looks like you mess up UAC only when you change permissions, resp. ownership of Registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserSwitch`. Setting the value each time at Logon seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that enabling the user switch via `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserSwitch` breaks UAC popups for standard (non-admin) users.

The alternative, hiding the list of users (http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9134-sign-screen-do-not-display-user-name-windows-10-a.html) requires typing in the user name.

What worked best for me was to non-intuitively enable auto-signin (http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3539-sign-user-account-automatically-windows-10-startup.html). If you put an empty username and password, the sign-in screen will:

1. Prompt with user "Other User"
2. From here you can click OK
3. You can then click whatever family account to sign-in from the bottom left list.

The extra click for the OK was an acceptable compromise for me.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else using a version of Windows 10 *without* GPO, you can do this.

1. <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Enter `control userpasswords2` and click OK
3. Tick the box that says `Users must enter a username and password to use this computer`
4. Click OK

Done.

Comment: That's true, but this doesn't work if one of the user accounts does not have a password. In that case, it will login straight away, regardless of that setting.

Comment: This did not work for me.  The box was already checked, but the auto login occurs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your computer is set to only "show" the last user that logged in and since that user does not use a password, it simply logs in.  Set it up to show all users every time instead of only the last user to log in.

Comment: I'm not using Windows, so maybe it's really obvious, but: can you describe *"Set it up to show all users every time instead of only the last user to log in."*?