# 2 users on the PC - Both auto-login at the same time. How can I disable this?

Tags: windows-10, login, multiple-users

There are 2 users on my PC. My mother's and mine. **Every time my mother turns on the PC, I get logged in too.** This is present since tha latest update (Win 10 1709). 
**It's pretty weird since I have a password**, but my mother does not.

So whenever she uses the PC, and then wants to turn it off, windows asks if she really wants to turn it off, because I'm logged in too.

I have tried this, but this is only enough to disable auto-login of the last user when the PC is turned on: [Can I disable auto logon on windows 10 home](https://superuser.com/questions/952868/can-i-disable-auto-logon-on-windows-10-home)

How can I fix this problem?

The current look of this regedit entry:

[image: The current look of this regedit entry]

Comment: How do you know you are logged on? Is it just because of the message your mother sees when trying to shutdown? That message doesn’t actually say which user is logged on, it just says “other” users are logged on.

Comment: When I click on her pic to logout, it says there that I'm logged in. But I did not do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to reconfigure the autologin settings for both users using Sysinternals (now Microsoft) [autologin](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/autologon) and see if it goes away.

If you still got logged-in with both accounts I would simply disable the auto log-in for one of them instead of running mad.

If you still experience the same problem try to check if you are really got auto logged-in before with this simple VBScript:

```vb
Const ForAppending = 8
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\you\Desktop\ScriptLog.txt", ForAppending)
objFile.WriteLine Now
objFile.Close
```

Maybe it's a false alarm.

Comment: Disabled the auto-login, but nothing changes. Actually I just noticed that when I log in, all the system tray icons (on-startup softwares) are already there. So it's like it loads everything while the login screen appears. I can't decide wether it's because of the new update, or something strange caused by my tweaks in the regedit...

Comment: I don't really know how to use a vbs file. I've created a vbs file using the lines you gave. When I execute, it just shows an error window: https://i.imgur.com/G8wR48t.png