# How to stop Windows 10 automatically signing users in (in the background)

Tags: windows-10, auto-login, windows-10-v1709

This is slightly different to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/952868/can-i-disable-auto-logon-on-windows-10-home) and other questions because 1. All my users have a password, and 2. I still get the user selection screen on boot up.

My problem is though, that the last used user is getting automatically (read: invisibly) logged in, in the background. This machine is used mostly for gaming and the automatically logged in user is hijacking Steam which is causing problems for the actual person logging in (when it’s my kids and they don’t know why their games aren’t launching).

I have tried the fixes mentioned in the linked question above, although I’ve only done the registry fix for a single user. Does it need to be done for all users?

Comment: I bet it has something to do with the fact that Microsoft decided that everyone wants their programs being started at launch, which are in the RunOnce section of the registry. But its a hunch, not entirely sure.

Comment: @LPChip nice idea. There is nothing in RunOnce though.

Comment: There are multiple locations for RunOnce. Checked all of them? You have HK_LM, which is system wide, HK_CU which is for the user currently logged in, and you have those for each user in HK_Users.

Comment: @LPChip nothing in HKLM or HKCU.

Comment: Checked the CU while logged in as the user who is automatically logged in?

Comment: @LPChip yeah, checked all users as it isn’t limited to a particular one.

Comment: Aww... okay, then I don't know... :( Stupid Microsoft for implementing unwanted features. :P

Comment: @LPChip tell me about it. At least give an easy way to turn it off.

Comment: It is my understanding that this is a new feature of Windows 10 **v1709**.

Comment: @studiohack should be optional though. As usual, MS think they know what’s best for everyone.

Comment: @Win32Guy yes, same problem and solution. My searches didn’t turn it up.

Comment: [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) is a program that lists all programs that start automatically. Also, if Steam does not work for one user, I would report that as a bug to Steam support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a solution that seems to work [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/windows-10-version-1709-last-user-remains-logged/2c917600-8d3a-487e-a280-4ba88fa27675). For each user I had to disable the setting

> automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart

In `Settings | Accounts | Sign-in options`. This is a completely mis-named option as it happens every time even when no updates or anything has occurred.

Comment: Thanks, this was really bugging me. I use a KVM, so if I started my windows PC in the background, it would automatically login in the background and screw up the rendering of the taskbar and chrome, etc, as it was defaulting to the DPI setting of my connected HDMI TV which is usually off.