# Windows 10 skips initial screen, goes right to screen saying user locked out; can't select another

Tags: boot, windows-10, user-accounts

This problem is keeping me from logging in to my PC.  The PC has two local users (neither is tied to a Microsoft logon).  One is a regular user with time restrictions; one is an administrator.  Starting this morning, the PC goes right to the screen saying the regular user is locked out, and when you press OK, it goes right back to that screen.  I don't have the opportunity to select the other user.  This condition persists across reboots.

The regular user's time restrictions should not be active now in any case.

I tried booting to the command-prompt to remove the time restrictions on the user.  I am able to login as the admin to get the boot command prompt, but it doesn't look like I can administer the PC's users from that prompt; the net user command doesn't show the real user list.

Any way to get out of this lockout loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected answer to [this question about preventing automatic login to the last user](https://superuser.com/questions/947040/how-to-prevent-automatic-login-of-the-last-user-in-windows-10) provided the key.

To get out of this state, I had to

1. Boot to the Recovery command prompt
2. Go into regedit and load the hive from C:\windows\system32\config\SOFTWARE
3. In that hive, change the value of the Enabled member of the key Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Authentication/LogonUI/UserSwitch to 1
4. Unload the hive
5. Exit the command prompt

When you reboot, you have the opportunity to select another user