# Windows 10 - switch users - with AD users

Tags: windows-10, active-directory

Windows 10 does actually have the option of switching between users assigned to a computer. But it seems that this will only work with LOCAL USERS not with AD users. Whenever an AD user logs off/Shuts down - the only user which comes up on start screen is the last one to logon!

I have tried adding a script to GPO Logon on User Configuration, in order to change registry key as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/947040/how-to-prevent-automatic-login-of-the-last-user-in-windows-10), but it seems to take no affect.

Since we have at work a few stations used by multiple AD users per station it is in need to switch users easily and not start typing Username every time someone logs of/Shuts down.

Does anyone have any suggestion for AD users?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch users through the Start menu:

[image]

Just click on the name of the currently logged in user and it will show you the accounts you can switch to.

If you want old way of doing it press alt+F4 to bring up the 'Switch User' option.

Comment: Sorry, but I may have not been clear enough. I am specifically asking about the situation where NO ONE is logged on at the moment! In that case ONLY the last one to logon appears (in AD users) where as in local users - although NO ONE is logged on - still all assigned users appear as buttons on the START screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add loopback processing mode to "merge" into the policy you created because it's a user policy that needs to be applied on computer level.

From this Microsoft link, [Changing loopback processing mode to merge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/231287) ,
that explains how to do it:

In order to do that you need to edit the policy for the following :

1. In the Group Policy Microsoft Management Console (MMC), click Computer Configuration.
2. Expand administrative templates
3. Select system
4. Select Group Policy
5. Enable Loopback Policy option
6. Set its mode to "Merge"